# Форматирование JSON PHP

Tags: php, json

При выводе `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Выводится отформатированная запись, но используется в качестве разделителей 4 пробела, я в коде использую 2 пробела. Вопрос в том как научить эту функцию выводить данные используя 2 пробела.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$json_indented_by_4 = json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$json_indented_by_2 = preg_replace('/^(  +?)\\1(?=[^ ])/m', '$1', $json_indented_by_4);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.